# Modelling a binary variable in LPs

Tags: linear-programming, binary-variable, big-m, indicator-constraints

I need your help.
I'm setting up an LP and I'm trying to find constraints to introduce the binary varibale $b_{ij}$. So it should take the value 0 if the sum of all $a_{ij}$ values to the period t are $\le n~ \forall i \in I \text{ and } j \in J$. $n$ being a not yet defined whole number. Otherwise, it is supposed to take the value 1. I think one models the whole thing with Big-M, but how exactly I do not know unfortunately.

Comment: Is $a_{ij}$ a decision variable?  If so, what type?  Is $n$ a decision variable or an input parameter?  How do $i$ and $j$ relate to $t$?

Comment: $a_{ij}$ is also either 0 or 1. It indicates whether seller $i$ sold all of his products in period $j$. If so, it is $=1$

Comment: So you want to model the following for all $i$ and $t$? $$b_{it} = 0 \iff \sum_{j \le t} a_{ij} \le n$$

Comment: Yep that's correct

Answer (score 3):

You want to enforce
$$b_{it} = 0 \iff \sum_{j \le t} a_{ij} \le n.$$
You can enforce
$$b_{it} = 0 \implies \sum_{j \le t} a_{ij} \le n$$
with big-M constraint
$$\sum_{j \le t} a_{ij} - n \le M_1 b_{it},$$
where $M_1 = |\{j\in J: j \le t\}| - n$.

You can enforce
$$\sum_{j \le t} a_{ij} \le n \implies b_{it} = 0,$$
equivalently its contrapositive
$$b_{it} = 1 \implies \sum_{j \le t} a_{ij} \ge n + 1,$$
with big-M constraint
$$n + 1 - \sum_{j \le t} a_{ij} \le M_2 (1 - b_{it}),$$
where $M_2 = n + 1$.

Another way to think of this is that you want $\sum_{j \le t} a_{ij}$ to be between $\color{red}{0}$ and $\color{red}{n}$ if $b_{it}=0$ and between $\color{blue}{n+1}$ and $\color{blue}{U_t}=|\{j\in J: j \le t\}|$ if $b_{it}=1$, yielding
$$\color{red}{0}(1-b_{it}) + (\color{blue}{n+1})b_{it} \le \sum_{j \le t} a_{ij} \le \color{red}{n}(1-b_{it}) + \color{blue}{U_t} b_{it}$$

Answer (score -1):

$ \sum_{j\le t} a_{i,j} \le n + Mb_{i,j}$
$ n+\epsilon \le \sum_{j \le t} a_{i,j} + M(1-b_{i,j})$
with $ \epsilon$ as a small number, depending upon expected values of $n$

Comment: @RobPratt summing over $t$